# Simple css: overlaying divs shifted one pixel

Tags: css, html

I want text2 to appear overlaying but shifted 1 pixel to the right of text1 (shadow effect, sort of).

I've put each in a nested div with position:relative; I've set z-index 1 and 2

However, the two texts still appear one below the other.  The workaround is to make the top in text2 *minus* 28, but what am I missing about the concepts relative and z-index?

HTML:

> ```
> <body>
> <div id='titles'>
>   <div id='text1'>Text For Testing This</div>     <div id='text2'>Text For Testing This</div>
> </div>
> </body>
> ```

CSS:

> ```
> body {
>   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   font-size:62.5%;
>   background-color:#666666;
> }
> #titles {
>   color:#FFFFFF;
>   width:800px;
>   font-size:2rem;
>   margin-left:auto;
>   margin-right:auto;
> }
> #text1 {
>   position:relative;
>   width:98%;
>   top:8px;
>   left:8px;
>   z-index:1;
>   }
> #text2  {
>   position:relative;
>   width:98%;
>   top:8px;
>   left:9px;
>   color:#000000;
>   z-index:2;
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You will want the positions to be absolute instead of relative. Because relative puts it relative to the previous element while absolute puts it absolute to its parent. [See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Luey2/1/).

```
#titles {
  position:relative;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  width:800px;
  font-size:2rem;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
#text1 {
  position:absolute;
  width:98%;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
  z-index:2;
  }
#text2  {
  position:absolute;
  width:98%;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  color:#000000;
  z-index:1;
  }​​
```

Comment: Yes, but now they're positioned top left of the window, not top left of the parent div, which is central to the window

Comment: @user1363157: That's because of the parent's `position`, change the `position` of the parent to `relative` if you want to resolve that issue. You will want the container to be relative such that the elements inside the container are absolute wrt the container and not wrt to the page...

Comment: Many thanks - that seems to work.   Need to get my head round why the containing div needs to be relative (to what? It's already centred by the margin:autos....) Need to study the book again.....

Comment: @user1363157: I believe it takes the first parent for which an absolute position is specified, because otherwise it does not know what the `normal flow` is. When in doubt, [check out to the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme). Haven't read through it myself, but I find it more useful than Googling / Tutorials / Books to resolve issues as the standard outlines *why* it has to be in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#text1 {
   position:absolute; // it's relative in your css
   width:98%;
   top:8px;
  left:8px;
  z-index:1;
}
#text2  {
  position:absolute; // it's relative in your css
  width:98%;
  top:8px;
  left:9px;
  color:#000000;
  z-index:2;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/mrLg8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `text1, text2` position to absolute and the `titles` position to relative, then the text divs will be positioned relative to titles.

```
#titles {
  position:relative;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  width:800px;
  font-size:2rem;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
#text1 {
  position:absolute;
  width:98%;
  top:8px;
  left:8px;
  z-index:1;
}
#text2  {
  position:absolute;
  width:98%;
  top:8px;
  left:9px;
  color:#000000;
  z-index:2;
}
```